# How to apply a function on the output of nn.conv(). nn.conv3d()

Tags: tensorflow

Assume I have a output from `3D nn.conv()`,or `nn.conv3d()`

The output is a tensor in following shape:

```
[1(batch),28(depth), 28(rows), 28(cols), 32(channels)]
<tf.Tensor 'Relu_1:0' shape=(1, 28,28, 28, 32) dtype=float32>
```

I want to apply a function on each 28x28x28 volume data. I really do not understand what the data looks like inside. Why should it not be (channels,28,28,28)? I could think it as a np.array.

I saw it could be done by:

```
function_to_map = f(x)
res = tf.map_fn(f, input)
```

But I do not know how to define function `f` on this tensor. I am really confused the channel here and what is the data looks like inside.

Answer (score 0):

conv1=tf.pack([tf.py_func(func,[tf.unpack(conv1)[i]],[tf.float32])[0] for i in range(n)])

The input for func is numpy.array and the output of the function is also numpy array. func could be any python function. The data is (b,c,d) if the tensor is (n,b,c,d)  n is the batch size. Finally figured it out.